# scrlayer-scrpage pagestyle on interleaf pages

Tags: koma-script, scrbook, scrlayer-scrpage

I want to change the pagestyle of the interleaf pages. My current example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead{\pagemark} 
\ihead{\headmark} 
\chead{} 
\ofoot{}\ifoot{}\cfoot{}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \Blinddocument
    \clearpage
    \blindtext
    \cleardoublepage
    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Page 18 is an interleaf page and its pagestyle is empty. I'd like to change the pagestyle to scrheadings so that I have the same header like on the other pages. I'm pretty sure that I saw an option some time ago but now I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The pagestyle of interleaf pages can be set by

```
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=scrheadings}
```